# Как вставить шаблон на страницу при помощи vanillaJS?

Tags: javascript, handlebars

При вставке шаблона в html браузер вываливает ошибку в консоль, о том, что передаваемый параметр не является узлом DOM:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Собственно, вопрос, как можно вставить шаблон в html-документ на ванильном скрипте? Хотелось бы в три строчки, как это делается на Jquery на оф. сайте handlebars

```
var data = {
      "array": [
    {
      "position": "one",
      "data": "Тут находятся какие-то данные"
    },
    {
      "position": "two",
      "data": "Тут находятся другие данные"
    },
    {
      "position": "three",
      "data": "Тут нет данных вообще, кроме этой записи"
    }
  ]
}

var source = document.getElementById("template").innerHTML;
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

document.body.appendChild((template(data)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение в одну строчку, как было нужно по условию на vanillaJS:

Вместо: `document.body.appendChild(container);`

```
container.innerHTML = template(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

В результате вызова функции `template` получается строка, которая была сформирована путем вставки данных в исходный шаблон. Пример с jQuery работает потому, что в [jQuery.append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) можно передать HTML строку - jQuery ее самостоятельно распарсит, создаст элемент и добавит на страницу. Однако [Node.appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) принимает только уже существующий элемент. Это можно решить создав элемент вручную, назначив свойству элмента `innerHTML` значение получившийся HTML строки и добавив элемент на страницу. Как и в случае с jQuery браузер распарсит ее и создаст нужный DOM.

```
var html = template(data);

var container = document.createElement('div');
container.innerHTML = html;

document.body.appendChild(container);
```

[Пример на JSBin](http://jsbin.com/vuceziculo/edit?html,js,output)

**Добавлено**

В примере выше будет создан дополнительный элемент, который оборачивает шаблон, что часто будет мешать. Можно обойтись без дополнительного элемента использовав [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment). Это так называемый контейнер, сам по себе не являющийся полноценным элементом, но поддержиавющий многие его функции. При вставке его на страницу, вставлено будет только его содержимое. Т.к. он не поддерживает `innerHTML`, то содержимое нужно будет перекинуть в него из "реального" промежуточного элемента:

```
var html = template(data);

var container = document.createElement('div');
container.innerHTML = html;

var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

// appendChild "вырезает" детей
while (container.childNodes[0]) {
    fragment.appendChild(container.childNodes[0]);
}

document.body.appendChild(fragment);
```

[Пример на JSBin](http://jsbin.com/dopevinazi/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: - Какой метод в итогу будет работать быстрее? Исопльзование нативного DocumentFragment (который, насколько я знаю не из самых быстрых) или вставка при помощи jquery.html?

Comment: Вот есть тест для сравнения: [documentFragment appendChild vs jquery append](https://jsperf.com/documentfragment-appendchild-vs-jquery-append/65) - по результатам моих запусков любая реализация с использованием jQuery всегда проигрывает на 60-80%

Comment: - Спасибо за помощь!